# How to draw a Tikz diagram for the parallel canonical form (with two integrators) of a linear control system with two phase variables?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I need help in drawing a Tikz diagram for the parallel canonical form (with two integrators) of a linear control system with two phase variables.

I enclosed the diagram for the parallel canonical form.

Your help is kindly appreciated - Thanks!

[image: Parallel Canonical Form]

Comment: You can start with https://texample.net/tikz/examples/noise-shaper/.

Comment: With your reputation you should know better, don't you? ... Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With recent Ti*k*Z, using libraries `arrows.meta`, `chains`, `positioning` and `quotes`:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm and 6mm,
  start chain = A going right,
  start chain = B going right,
   arr/.style = {-{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}},
every edge/.style = {draw, arr},
every edge quotes/.append style = {auto, inner ysep=1pt, font=\footnotesize},
   lbl/.style = {pos=0.95, #1, inner sep=2pt, xshift=-1pt, font=\tiny},
 lbl/.default = left,
   box/.style = {draw, semithick, minimum size = 1em},
   int/.style = {draw, semithick, minimum height = 4ex,
                 font=\Huge, node contents={$\int$},
                },
   sum/.style = {circle, draw, semithick, minimum size = 1em,
                 inner sep=0pt, font=\large, node contents={$+$},
                },
                    ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={fill=red!30, on chain=A}]
\coordinate (aux);  % A-1
\node[sum];         % A-2
\node[int];
\node[box] {$2$};
\node[sum];
\coordinate[right=13mm of A-5] (aux);
\node[box, below=of A-3] {$-1$};
    \end{scope}
%
\path   (A-1) edge["$u$"] coordinate (aux1)
              node[lbl, above] {$-$}   (A-2)
        (A-2) edge["$\dot{x}_1$"]   (A-3)
        (A-3) edge        coordinate (aux2) (A-4)
        (A-4) edge                  (A-5)
        (A-5) edge["$2x_1-x_2$"]    (A-6);
\draw[arr]  (aux2) |- (A-7);
\draw[arr]  (A-7) -| (A-2) node[lbl] {$+$};
%%%%
    \begin{scope}[nodes={fill=red!30, on chain=B}]
\node[sum, below=13mm of A-2];   % B-1
\node[int];
\node[box] {$-1$};
\node[box, below=of B-2] {$-2$};
    \end{scope}
%
\path   (B-1) edge["$\dot{x}_2$"]   (B-2)
        (B-2) edge["$x_2$"] coordinate (aux3) (B-3);
\draw[arr]  (aux1) |- (B-1)  node[lbl=above] {$-$};
\draw[arr]  (B-3)  -| (A-5) node[lbl] {$+$};
\draw[arr]  (aux3) |- (B-4);
\draw[arr]  (B-4)  -| (B-1) node[lbl] {$+$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is so beautiful - Thanks a lot. 

As advised by regulars here, I will wait for 2 days, look at all answers (if there are more), and then accept the most interesting one. Thank you so much again.

Comment: Ok. However meanwhile you can try to draw this scheme yourself. As starting point use example given in the link in the @user187803 comment. Example is quite elementary and with old syntax. If you will not try yourself, you will never learn how to draw such relative simple schemas.

Comment: Zarko: The arrow to the right of $u$ enters the junction box with '+' sign only and not '-' sign as shown above. How do I change this '-' to '+' ? Thanks!

Comment: node[lbl, above] {$+$}   (A-2) [Is this Okay? Thanks]

Comment: I try reproduce showed image. with exception that style for `sum` is as I usually use. Until you will not provide what you tryx so far, I will suggest to close your question as "Needs details or clarity"

Comment: Thanks - I understood what to do! Your answer is clear.